# Pandas: How to return the list of values which are not in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['CAD123', 'MXN789', 'EUR567','JPY224', 'EUR673', 'PLN254'], 
           'currency': ['CAD', 'MXN', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'EUR','PLN']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'currency':['EUR','PLN']})
```

Above are my two dataframes. I am doing some data analysis and want the list of values in 'name' column whose 'currency' is not there in another dataframe. My expected output as below. Please suggest.

```
Expected_list = ['CAD123','MXN789','JPY224']
```

Comment: _Please suggest._ Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do `isin` with `loc`

```
l = df1.loc[~df1.currency.isin(df2.currency), 'name'].tolist()
['CAD123', 'MXN789', 'JPY224']
```

Comment: Way tooo.. fast... +1

Comment: Is there a performance difference between using `.loc` and without, as `df1.name[~df1.currency.isin(df2.currency)].tolist()`?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney it is better not chain the slice ~

Comment: YOBEN_S thanks for prompt suggestion. I was missing ~negate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
df1[~df1['currency'].isin(df2['currency'])]['name'].tolist()
```

Output:-

```
['CAD123', 'MXN789', 'JPY224']
```